# Question about pseudo-euclidean spaces and manifolds

Tags: general-topology, ordinary-differential-equations, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Is it possible to make a pseudo-euclidean space $ \mathbb{R}^{p, q} $ into a differentiable manifold?

My intuition tells me that yes since in special relativity we deal with the flat Minkowski space $ \mathbb{R}^{1, 3} $ however i tried to approach the problem of proving that for any given pseudo-euclidean space we can make it a differentiable manifold and i am stuck.

From what i understand, the way we prove this is by defining two charts $ (U, x) $ and $ (V, y) $  on local regions U and V in $M$ with two maps $ x: U \rightarrow A $ and $ y: V \rightarrow B $ where A and B are subsets of $ \mathbb{R}^{\dim(M)} $ and then looking at the transition maps $ y(x^{-1}(p)) $ to see if they are of class $ C^k $ and if they are for any pair of charts in M then M is a differentiable manifold

I tried to do this by defining a subset of $ \mathbb{R}^{1,2} $ as a collection of intervals.

$ U = ( (0;1); (1;2); (3; 4)) $

Which would mean my local region U would be from 0 to 1 in x, from 1 to 2 in y and from 3 to 4 in z.

And then i defined a map to be

$ \phi(p) = a_i p_i $

With $ a \in \mathbb{R} $ and then i did the same for V but with different intervals and different constants.

However when i evaluate the derivatives of the transition maps this is not $ C^k $

Help, i've literally never done this kind of exercises and now i'm stuck.
I don't know how to face this problem

Comment: Hint: One chart will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

OK, let's try to make sense of your question. First of all, what is ${\mathbb R}^{p,q}$? Let $n=p+q$. Then ${\mathbb R}^{p,q}$ is the vector space ${\mathbb R}^{n}$ equipped with the quadratic form
$$
Q({\mathbf x})= x_1^2+...+x_p^2 - x_{p+1}^2- ... - x_n^2. 
$$
In particular, as a **topological space,** ${\mathbb R}^{p,q}$ is just ${\mathbb R}^{n}$. (At this point it is critical that you know what the words "topological space" mean. I assume that you do.)

What does it mean to make ${\mathbb R}^{p,q}$ into a differentiable manifold? You want to accomplish two things:

1. Find a (maximal) smooth atlas on the topological space ${\mathbb R}^{n}$ such that the transition maps are smooth. (The "definition" that you wrote in your question is not quite the right one.) This will give ${\mathbb R}^{n}$ a structure of a differentiable manifold, I will call this manifold $M$.
2. Make sure that the quadratic form $Q$ becomes a **semi-Riemannian metric** on $M$ (of the signature $(p,q)$). (I assume that  you know what these words mean.)

Now, let's do it. As an atlas ${\mathcal A}$ on ${\mathbb R}^{n}$ I will take a single chart $(U,\phi)$, where $U={\mathbb R}^n$ (the entire space) and $\phi$ the identity map, $\phi({\mathbf x})={\mathbf x}$. Let's check the transition maps: Since there is only one chart, all what we have to check is that $\phi\circ \phi^{-1}$ and  $\phi^{-1}\circ \phi$ are smooth. But this is clear since both are just the identity map, so there is nothing to check here. Lastly, I will take a **maximal smooth atlas** containing ${\mathcal A}$ (this step is just a bookkeeping).  The result is a differentiable manifold structure on ${\mathbb R}^n$. This concludes Part 1.

For Part 2 you have to identify the **tangent spaces** $T_xM$ to our manifold $M$. Since $M$ is just ${\mathbb R}^n$, tangent vectors, elements of $T_xM$, are simply directed line segments $\overrightarrow{xy}$ with the tail at $x$ and the head at various points $y\in M$. I assume that in your vector calculus class you have learned how to identify the space of such segments with ${\mathbb R}^n$ itself (by computing the difference of coordinates of the points $x$ and $y$). With this identification, we define a quadratic form $Q_x$ on each $T_xM$ simply as our original form $Q$. If you want to be more explicit, for  $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$, $y=(y_1,...,y_n)$, we have
$$
Q_x(\overrightarrow{xy})= Q(y_1-x_1,,....,y_n-x_n)= 
(y_1-x_1)^2 + ... + (y_p-x_p)^2 - (y_{p+1}-x_{p+1})^2 - ... - (y_n-x_n)^2.
$$
The function $(x,y)\mapsto Q_x(\overrightarrow{xy})$ is clearly smooth, hence, making our collection of quadratic forms $Q_x$ a semi-Riemannian metric on our manifold $M$.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Is a semi-Riemannian metric the same as a pseudo-Riemannian one? And how is the identity map smooth? Shouldn't its derivatives be 0 since it's constant?

Comment: Semi-Riemannian is the more standard name as pseduo-Riemannian. As for rhe derivative of the function $f(x)=x$, one usually learns this in a vector calculus class. Did you take one?

Comment: In order to succeed in (mathematical) physics, you absolutely have to have a solid math foundation, including at least calculus and linear algebra. If you did not take these classes or forgot what you have learned there, my suggestion is to take a class or read a textbook on your own.

Comment: I know that the derivative of $ f(x) = x $ is 1  but for the transition maps to be smooth we need for their derivatives to be continous. As far as i know $ F(x) = 1 $ is not a continuous function since for any x and small dx $ x \rightarrow x + dx $ does not induce a change $ y \rightarrow y + dy $ since y is a constant function

Comment: Oh... you really need to retake calculus.... Or ask a new question on mayhstack exchange asking why constant functions are continuous.